# How to test "UDP header incorrect length" on your own?

Tags: security, testing, udp

I know UDP header incorrect length is usually part of security testing as this one could crash the target machine. However, how to do that on your own?

Answer (score 1):

Testing the header length of a packet is important part of security testing... if you are writing a TCP/IP stack.   But no one is going to test this on a penetration test because this will have little or no affect on a real world system.

Building strange packets is useful for testing firewalls, and [hping](http://www.hping.org/) is very useful for that (as well as nmap :).  [Here](http://www.radarhack.com/dir/papers/hping2_v1.5.pdf) is a good tutorial on using hping.  This following command is sending the largest UDP packet possible, if you try an encode a larger size you'll get a one's complement integer overflow due to bit boundaries (which isn't very useful).

`hping -2 -p 7 192.168.10.33 -d 65535 -E /root/signature.sig`

If you want to verify that a malformed packet is built correctly you should grab Wireshark.

Comment: So, you cannot crash any computer by sending a packet with invalid lenght?? Its mentioned almost in every penetration testing guide

Comment: @Tomas As a penetration tester I am 100% sure that no production tcp/ip stack is going to succumb to such a simple attack,  but your welcome to try it.  These low layer protocols have been heavy tested, your better off looking for memory corruption flaws in osi layer 7 (application),  layer 4 is very simple in comparison and there for less likely for something to go wrong.

Comment: @Tomas on a side note,  you are right about testing the length parameter.  often times this is used as an offset in a `memcpy()` or similar function.

Comment: The Rook: thank you! I have never meet any penetration tester, do you mind if discuss a few questions with you? Over email or whatever, I would really appreciate it. Just entering to this field. Thanks!

Comment: @Tomas sure what is your email?